# Some of the pages in admin Dashboard not loading, received Error in magento 2.0.6

Tags: magento2, error, catalog, admin-panel, magento-2.0.6

Catalog page not loading in admin dashboard of Magento 2.0.6.

Please see the error message below:

> Warning: Magento\Framework\Locale\TranslatedLists::getCountryTranslation(): Cannot load resource element 'AN' in vendor\magento\framework\Locale\TranslatedLists.php on line 206

Please help me to resolve the same.

Comment: did you reslove this problem ?

Comment: can you share some screenshots ?

Comment: thats my http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128428/magento-admin-catalog-page-error

Answer (score 0):

More than likely a Translation string for Netherlands Antilles is missing.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#AN
- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

Before line 206 you can possibly dump `$this->localeResolver->getLocale()` to determine which locale is attempting to be read.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Locale/TranslatedLists.php#L206

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem using

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

if  js or css files missing

run : `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` optional language